# Application to create custom icon theme on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, icon

I want an app that can create a custom icon theme from scratch, and modify icons such as for the "My Computer" folder and also for apps like "Magnifier" etc.

I know you can go into "desktop properties" but I want something more advanced than that.

I am thinking about this because I can't find a Windows XP icon theme for Windows 7. If I google that, it just comes up with a *Windows 7 icon theme for Windows XP*, which is **NOT** what I want.

There was IconTweaker, but it does not work on Windows 7. I want something like that which works on Windows 7.

Comment: We'll need much more information to provide a solid recommendation. Please, take some time to read through our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) and [edit] your question to match them. What requirements do you have? Just asking for an alternative to another piece of software isn't sufficient. What would be nice to have, but not required? After you [edit] your question to contain more information, we can reopen it. Thanks!